# Rails turn off console logging when rendering templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I have a collection of records from a table

I'm using them to make a javascript object for my javascript function to use

I made a helper method to loop through the array of records and build an array of hashes, then I convert it `to_json` and `html_safe`.

I also made a `json` template which outputs the same thing.

I'm curious to see which runs faster so I use Benchmark.

It works fine and I can see the results, but since one of the strategies is about rendering a template, it causes the console log to get cluttered:

```
                user     system      total        real
ruby method     0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.044988)
json template   Rendered dispatch/trucks/_locations.json.jbuilder (0.9ms)
  Rendered dispatch/trucks/_locations.json.jbuilder (0.9ms)
  Rendered dispatch/trucks/_locations.json.jbuilder (0.9ms)
  Rendered dispatch/trucks/_locations.json.jbuilder (0.8ms)

  ... hundreds of lines of logging

  Rendered dispatch/trucks/_locations.json.jbuilder (0.7ms)
  Rendered dispatch/trucks/_locations.json.jbuilder (0.7ms)
  Rendered dispatch/trucks/_locations.json.jbuilder (0.7ms)
  Rendered dispatch/trucks/_locations.json.jbuilder (0.7ms)
  0.190000   0.130000   0.320000 (  0.317963)
```

I was wondering if there's a way to prevent `"Rendered _template.json"` to stop appearing while I run my benchmark. Is there a way to toggle it somehow? I know you can toggle turning on and off database query logging with

```
# turns on database logger
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)

# turns off database logger
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil
```

I use those for testing and dubugging.

If I can't get an answer I might have to look through the source code but it's not that important and I'm just curious.